# BootStrap scrollspy configuration don't work at 100%

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

My problem is with scrollspy in BootStrap, don't work as it should. I test any different configuration in the web and not works. You can see the problem on my [site](http://chilenetware.com/nuevositio), when scrolling the menu does not work well.

I'm new using BootStrap, I have tried several possible solutions. Hopefully you can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Works ok for me in Firefox and Chrome. What browser do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE. The Reason might be due to division height. Since the division height of your product and Contact is to short, The spying menu is going faster to the next menus as u scroll. Try increasing the height of the division and text you see a difference for example

[Example](http://www.wndrmnt.com/#contact)

Don't use old browsers like IE8, you need external patch files to be added.